# Move objects closer when scrolling jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create 5 layers - divs. Each layer has different height, but spaces between them are same. For example:

```
Div 1
30px gap
Div 2
30px gap
Div 3
30px gap
```

And I need some jQuery script which will determine my page(body tag) height and when I scroll down smoothly change top(objects will be absolutely positioned, they need to overlap), or margin-top of them One by one.. First will go down layer 1 for 50px, then layer 1 with 2 for 50px, then first three layers for 50px... And at the end of the page they will all overlap by 20px(30px gap + 20px overlap). So I dont want to move all layers at once.

I hope this explanation is enough, I don't have any scripts yet, had some, but nothing worked. For better imagination, it is a burger splitted into: top bread, salad, bacon, meat, bottom bread. It will appear on side of one scroll webpage. At top it will be splitted and when user scrolls down, ingredients will overlap and at bottom of page they will complete one burger.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you idea where to start:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var margin_max = 30;
    var join_at = 70;
    var margin = Math.floor( margin_max - ($(window).scrollTop() * margin_max / join_at) );
    if(margin < 0) margin = 0;
    $('.part').css('margin-bottom', margin);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/L6DP5/1/

Of course you need modify it a little bit to suit your needs

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I need, I had similar script and could not move forward from it. I need at first overlap Div1 over Div2 - other divs do not have to move.. than 12 together over 3, than 123 together over 4 and then 1234 over 5. 5 will never move. All have to "fall down to 5" in that order.